# Why is Jquery $.ajax firing all statusCode on function call even with successful call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple Jquery ajax function call that looks like this.

```
function getUsers(){
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
        url: "../assets/js/data/users.json",
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        dataType: "json",
        statusCode: { 
            404: handleError404("Error at getUsers();"),
            500: handleError500("Error at getUsers();")
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                console.log(element.name);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The error handle functions look like this.

```
function handleError500(customMsg){
    alert("Oops, there was an error: 500");
    console.log("ERROR: 500 | "+customMsg);
}

function handleError404(customMsg){
    alert("Oops, there was an error: 404");
    console.log("ERROR: 404 | "+customMsg);
}
```

For some odd reason, even on a successful call with no apprent error 500 or 404 the statusCode functions are firing.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common Javascript gotcha, but you're actually `firing` off these functions!

`()` after the name will actually invoke that function at that moment.

```
404: handleError404() // <-- it calls it immidiately
```

What you need to do, is create an anonymous function, which will be called *later* when the error actually happens, which inside of it will invoke your functions.

```
    statusCode: { 
        404: function () { // <-- anonymous function won't get called until it needs to
            handleError404("Error at getUsers();")
        },
        500: function () { 
            handleError500("Error at getUsers();")
        }
    },
```

---

> Side note: If you **weren't passing in parameters** to your function,
>   you could actually ommit the *anonymous function* `function () { /*
>   function call */ }`  part, and just call your function!

```
statusCode: {
    404: handleErrors, // since no parameters are passed, this could be done
    500: handleErrors
}
```

Comment: mcpDESIGNS got to this before I could :-) - to further clarify, you would do `404: handleError404()` when you want to set statusCode.404 to the value returned by the function `handleError404`. So of course it has to execute the function to return the value (which in your case above, nothing is returned)

Comment: You also need to know that statusCode is called both on success and error result. See jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the definition of the property of the object you are actually calling the function instead of defining one to be called when the code actually happens.

One thing you can try is:

```
    statusCode: { 
        404: function() { handleError404("Error at getUsers();") },
        500: function() { handleError500("Error at getUsers();") }
    },
```